# Можно ли приостановить закрытие AlertDialog

Tags: android

Такой вопрос:
Существует экземпляр `AlertDialog` с добавленным `View` (например, `EditText`). Можно ли в обработчике при добавлении `setPositiveButton` добавить код, который не закрывает диалог при условии неподходящего состояния `View` (например, `EditText.GetText==""`) ?

Answer (score 3):

```
mDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (EditText.GetText()=="") mDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        else mDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    }
                });
```

Как-то так ...

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, китайцы всё для таких как я чайников разжевали: http://overoid.tistory.com/29